# divide an array into multiple arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to do this in C++.

Read a text file which is like:

```
2
2 10 1 2 7
3 8 3 7 7 10 7
```

The first line indicates how many paths exist in my design.
The second and third lines are those lines(the first number indicates 2 pairs, so 10,1 and 2,7 are 2 pairs)
The first element in the third line indicates 3 pairs and the pairs are 8,3 and 7,7 and 10,7.

I have been able to read the text file and store these into ONE array. However, I need to divide them up and have each line in a seperate array.

So for example

array alpha to contain 10,1 and 2,7
array beta to contain 8,3 and 7,7, and 10,7

It would be super awesome if I could just create multiple arrays based on the first line. So if the user entered 2 I create 2 arrays or 3 for 3 arrays and put each line into each array. Can someone help please?

Cheers :)

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?  Can you show the code you're describing?

Comment: Well I don't know how to write this code so that when user enters 3
 and next lines are:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2 

create 3 arrays based on this
Array Alpha contains 1 2 3 4
Array Beta contains 5 6 7 8
Array Gama contains 9 0 1 2

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

- After reading N from the first line, allocate an array of N pointers
- For each subsequent line, you can allocate the array for that line since you know its size from the first value in the line.

Comment: Can you please show how to implement this code? I want this to be done: User enters 3
Next lines are:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2 

and create 3 arrays based on this
Array Alpha contains 1 2 3 4
Array Beta contains 5 6 7 8
Array Gama contains 9 0 1 2

Comment: @ShahinB: If you post the code you describe in the question, I can explain how to modify it to do what is described above.